# How to convert numpy object array into str/unicode array?

Tags: python, string, numpy, type-conversion

**Update:**  In lastest version of numpy (e.g., v1.8.1), this is no longer a issue. All the methods mentioned here now work as excepted.

**Original question:**  Using object dtype to store string array is convenient sometimes, especially when one needs to modify the content of a large array without prior knowledge about the maximum length of the strings, e.g.,

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([u'abc', u'12345'], dtype=object)
```

At some point, one might want to convert the dtype back to unicode or str. However, simple conversion will truncate the string at length 4 or 1 (why?), e.g.,

```
>>> b = np.array(a, dtype=unicode)
>>> b
array([u'abc', u'1234'], dtype='<U4')
>>> c = a.astype(unicode)
>>> c
array([u'a', u'1'], dtype='<U1')
```

Of course, one can always iterate over the entire array explicitly to determine the max length,

```
>>> d = np.array(a, dtype='<U{0}'.format(np.max([len(x) for x in a])))
array([u'abc', u'12345'], dtype='<U5')
```

Yet, this is a little bit awkward in my opinion.  Is there a better way to do this?

**Edit to add:**  According to this [closely related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1582525/longest-string-in-numpy-object-array),

```
>>> len(max(a, key=len))
```

is another way to find out the longest string length, and this step seems to be unavoidable...

Comment: Not a solution, but `max(len(x) for x in a)` is probably faster than constructing a list and calling `np.max`.

Comment: I edited the question just before your comment:D `max(a, key=len)` is even faster.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I know this is an old question but in case anyone comes across it and is looking for an answer, try

```
c = a.astype('U')
```

and you should get the result you expect:

```
c = array([u'abc', u'12345'], dtype='<U5')
```

Answer (score 5):

At least in Python 3.5 Jupyter 4 I can use:

```
a=np.array([u'12345',u'abc'],dtype=object)
b=a.astype(str)
b
```

works just fine for me and returns:

```
array(['12345', 'abc'],dtype='<U5')
```

Comment: seems like if the array was initialised with `dtype == np._str`, using `astype(str)` will not convert the dtype

Comment: Check this out:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30086936/what-is-the-difference-between-the-types-type-numpy-string-and-type-str